# PHP echo with $substr

Tags: php

I've wrote this code:

```
<?php $offset = 0;  ?>
<?php  $Counter = 0; ?>
<?php $IsRD = 1; ?>
<?php $temp = 0;  ?>
<?php $TmpString = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getprojector_compatibility()) , 'projector_compatibility');?>

<?php echo "<table border=\"0\" align=\"center\">"; ?>
<?php echo "<tr><th><h1>Compatibility:</h1></th></tr>"; ?>

<?php  if(strpos(  $TmpString, ";") == 0){  
    $Counter++; 
    $IsRD++;
    echo "<tr><td>The #$Counter is at position - 0 </td>";
 } ?>

<?php 
while($offset = strpos( $TmpString, ";", $offset + 1)){     

    if ($IsRD == 3) {
        $Counter++;
        $IsRD++;    
        echo "<td>" , $substr($TmpString,$temp,$offset-$temp) , "</td></tr><tr>";
        $IsRD=1;
        $temp=$offset;
    }
    else {
        $IsRD++;
        $Counter++;
**line 171** echo "<td>", $substr($TmpString,$temp,$offset-$temp),"</td>";
        $temp=$offset;
    }   
 } ?>
<?php echo "</tr></table>";  ?>
```

and when I run it I get this error:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in /home/...../view.phtml
>   on line 171

What am I missing / doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the line must be

```
substr($TmpString,$temp,$offset-$temp)
```

not

```
$substr($TmpString,$temp,$offset-$temp)
```

You've got also wrong code in echo lines, like this one:

```
echo "<td>" , $substr($TmpString,$temp,$offset-$temp) , "</td></tr><tr>";
```

Replace commas with dots (string concatenation operator) and do what I wrote above with dollar sign ($)

```
echo "<td>" . substr($TmpString,$temp,$offset-$temp) . "</td></tr><tr>";
```

And better readable coding style:

```
echo "<td>". substr($TmpString,$temp,$offset-$temp) ."</td></tr><tr>";
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove the "$" from the substr.

```
echo "<td>", substr($TmpString,$temp,$offset-$temp),"</td>";
```

PHP tried to lookup the value of the variable "$substr" which was not set to anything and use that as the function name. Since $substr was not set, it used the value empty string "" as the function name and produced that (unhelpful) error message about illegal function name.

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `$` before the name of `substr` in that line that needs to be removed.

The current version instructs PHP to look at the contents of the (hypothetical) variable `$substr`, which is expected to contain a string, and call the function whose name is equal to that string (PHP calls this [*variable functions*](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php)).

Of course there's no variable `$substr` in your code, hence the error.